# swift http request can't get non-200 response

Tags: ios, swift

I am using below swift code to make a http request. If the server response 200 OK response, swift can work properly. However, the completionHandler callback never get called until timeout when the server response other than 200 status. Is there any other setting on swift to prevent receiving other status response?

```
let urlStr = "http://xxxxx"
let url = NSURL(string: urlStr)!
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
request.HTTPMethod = "post"
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
    guard let _:NSData = data, let _:NSURLResponse = response where error == nil else {
                // no response code
        print("response")
        return
    }
    print("get response from register service \(data) \(error)")         
})
task.resume()
```

If that happens, I get timeout error below:

> get login response nil error:Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://XXXXX, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://localhost:8080/nurse/login, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2103, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.})

Also I tested with curl command and I was able to get the response as below. So the server side works fine for me. I believe the problem is on the client side.

```
$ curl -i -X POST -d 'mobile=1234' http://localhost:8080/nurse/login
HTTP/1.1 10029 
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Application-Context: application
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: access_token
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 18
Date: Thu, 24 Mar 2016 02:39:09 GMT
```

Comment: what does your error variable says?

Comment: It says timeout.  See this:
get login response nil error:Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://localhost:8080/nurse/login, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://localhost:8080/nurse/login, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2103, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.})

Comment: There is a potential your server is not sending out non-2xx responses.

Comment: @diatrevolo  I have verified with browser and postman that my server did send non-200 response.

Comment: @user3069232: I never heard about NSMutableURLRequest going away. I just read about NSURLConnection going away and being replaced with shared session.

Comment: My mistake, comment deleted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a server side problem. The code below works (in Playground):

Try using this url and see if this is happening for you.

Also, I would use a simple tool like curl to test manually your server side before debugging Swift code:

```
curl -i -X POST -d 'name=yoyo' http://putsreq.com/vccZnwiNpP23RF7nwOPE
```

**EDIT**

Here is a function that does what you want. I hardcoded your URL and things are working now.

```
func postSomeStuff(data: String, completion: (data: NSData?, error: NSError?)->Void) {

    let post: NSString = "data=\(data)"
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://123.56.184.207:8080/nurse/login")!
    let postData = post.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!

    let postLength = String(postData.length)

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.HTTPBody = postData
    request.setValue(postLength, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("*/*", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    config.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 120
    config.timeoutIntervalForResource = 240

    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { urlData, response, reponseError in

        if let receivedData = urlData {
            let res = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse!;

            NSLog("Response code: %ld", res.statusCode);

            if 200..<300 ~= res.statusCode {
                completion(data: receivedData, error: nil)
            } else {
                let returnedError = NSError(domain: "getSomeStuff", code: 1, userInfo: [:])
                completion(data: nil, error: returnedError)
            }
        } else {
            var userInfo: [NSObject: AnyObject] = [:]
            if let error = reponseError {
                userInfo["message"] = error.localizedDescription
                userInfo["cause"] = error
            }
            let returnedError = NSError(domain: "myFunc", code: 2, userInfo: userInfo)
            completion(data: nil, error: returnedError)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}

postSomeStuff("yoyo") { data , err in
    if let data = data { print(data) }
    if let err = err { print(err) }
}

let sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);


// Used only in Playground
XCPSetExecutionShouldContinueIndefinitely(true)
```

Comment: I just run curl and get the response immediately. Please see below output. The status is 10029.    localhost:cooltoo_backend yzzhao$ curl -i -X POST -d 'mobile=1234' http://localhost:8080/nurse/login
HTTP/1.1 10029 
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Application-Context: application
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: access_token
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 18
Date: Thu, 24 Mar 2016 02:39:09 GMT

Comment: in order to make it clear, I added the output on my original question, please take a look at.

Comment: I posted an edit to my response with some sample code that does what you want.

Comment: Thanks for showing me the code. I have run your code on my playground, but I am still facing the issue. The server side has response but the xcode are not able to get the response until timeout. Or you can try to access this link with the above code:  http://123.56.184.207:8080/nurse/login

Comment: I added timeouts to the session configuration and things are working for me using your URL.

Comment: what did you get? Did you get timeout error or any other error information?

Comment: 2016-03-24 08:03:42.211 TestHttpPost[28185:826796] Response code: 200
<48545450 2f312e31 20313030 3239200d 0a536572 7665723a ... 697374>

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer if it addresses the main question (since I got it to work) and moving all other development questions pertaining to your foray into mobile app dev to chat.stackoverflow.com if you need anymore support out of the scope of this question. Thanks.

Comment: I just tried your code and the server response an error status. In this case, the client doesn't get response

Comment: Try to turn off your VPN. If I can access your server remotely and you are unable to do it wherever you are, I would start debugging the local network.

Comment: I works perfect after I turn off my VPN. Thanks a lot for your help.